# How to find "?" values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to read a CSV file in a dataframe which has `"?"` values in some of the rows.

I want to find the rows which contain these values (?) over all the columns

I tried using loc but it returns an Empty Dataframe

```
test_df.loc(test_df['rbc'] == "?"]
test_df.loc(test_df['rbc'] == None]
```

This returns an Empty DataFrame

I want to iterate the dataframe over all the columns

Can someone suggest a way to do this

Comment: Can you add data sample?

Comment: you can use contains function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want check `?` values only in all columns:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, (df.astype(str) == '?').any()]
```

More general if want check all possible substrings `?` in all columns:

```
df2 = df.loc[:, df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains('\?')).any()]
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,'?',2,3],
                   'D':['?',3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,'?'],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  ?  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  ?  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  ?  b
```

You can create boolean `DataFrame` first and then check [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) True per rows and per columns for filtering:

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains('\?'))
df2 = df.loc[mask.any(axis=1), mask.any()]
print (df2)
   C  D  E
0  7  ?  5
3  ?  7  9
5  3  0  ?
```

Detail:

```
print (mask)
       A      B      C      D      E      F
0  False  False  False   True  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False   True  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False   True  False

print (mask.any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool

print (mask.any())
A    False
B    False
C     True
D     True
E     True
F    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael , the general solutions makes it more robust

Comment: OK, so you need return all columns? Or all rows in column `rbc` ?

Comment: All columns for the rows which contains ?

Comment: Super, so my solution return what you need?

Comment: Yeah for all the columns whose dtypes are object , not all columns though

Comment: Hmm, I convert it to `str`, so it should working nice.

Comment: is there a way to only limit to rows which contains (?) , the current solution returns all the rows

Comment: @VaibhavSharma - can you cjheck my answer?

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

```
result = test_df[test_df['rbc'].str.contains("?")]
```

Comment: @NayanaMadhu - OP need `I want to iterate the dataframe over all the columns` - and you check only one column, I think your answer is wrong...